# Custom URL Within Custom Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, url-rewrite, redirect

There seem to be a few similar questions out there but I am struggling to find one that relates to what I need.

I have a custom module that has a View controller. A sample URL would be:

```
/our-stores/index/view/id/2
```

I would like to change this to something similar to:

```
/our-stores/this-is-a-store
or /this-is-a-store.html
or /our-stores/view/this-is-a-store
```

I'm sure you get the idea.

I have tried adding a url redirect as follows:

```
$store_url = str_replace(' ', '-', $store_model->getStoreTitle());
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                    ->setIsSystem(0)
                    ->setOptions('RP')
                    ->setIdPath($store_url)
                    ->setTargetPath('our-stores/view/index/id/' . $store_model->getId())
                    ->setRequestPath($store_url)
                    ->save();
```

This seems to partially work; if I go to `/this-is-a-store` it goes to the correct page by changes the URL in the address bar back to `/our-stores/index/view/id/2`

Can anyone please help me with a nice, clean way of achieving what I need?

If you need anything off me, please ask and I will provide.

Comment: you have to create custom router for your extension. http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out myself and thought I'd share for anyone else who stumbled on this issue.

I simply changed the code in the question to:

```
$rewrite
    ->setIsSystem(0)
    ->setIdPath('store_' . $store_model->getId())
    ->setTargetPath('our-stores/view/index/id/' . $store_model->getId())
    ->setRequestPath($store_url)
    ->save();
```

The change that made the difference was not setting `options` to 'RF'.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the url in magento admin panel itself.

```
Type - Custom 
Request path – /our-stores/index/view/id/2 
Targeted path - /our-stores/this-is-a-store
```

you can refer this link also [rewite](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/url-rewriting)

Comment: This seems to only work for categories and static CMS pages. Like I mentioned in my question, this is for a custom extension. I will need the pages to be created programmatically

Comment: No. you can add your own page url also same as you do for CMS page and product. it will be redirected. Try it